# Recuperar un check activo según el valor de la Base de Datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Tengo un formulario en el que tengo un check dinámico, si lo activo me muestra dos campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El check lo guado en un campo en la BD llamado checked_craft

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que si el valor en BD es = 1 me muestre el check marcado cuando vuelvo abrir el formulario

mi código es el siguiente

```html
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM document");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$check_craft = $result['checked_craft'];
?>

<div class="ln_solid"></div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="mostrar3"></label>
  <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-offset-1" style="color:#26B99A"><strong>RESPUESTA</strong></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name='mostrar3' id="mostrar3" class='squaredThreex fantasma3 hh' value="<?php if ($check_craft = 1) echo " checked ";?>">
  <div id="contentM3" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="mod_craft" value="" id="mod_craft" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 " placeholder="No Oficio">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="mod_datecraft" value="" id="mod_datecraft" class="form-control craftdatetimepicker col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Fecha Oficio">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ln_solid"></div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fantasma3').click(function() {
      if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#contentM3').hide();
      } else {
        $('#contentM3').show();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No solo necesitas setear el valor, tambien necesitas agregar `checked` como atributo.  Algo asi:

```
<div class="ln_solid"></div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="mostrar3"></label>
  <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-xs-offset-1" style="color:#26B99A"><strong>RESPUESTA</strong></label>
  <input type="checkbox" name='mostrar3' id="mostrar3" class='squaredThreex fantasma3 hh' value="<?php echo $check_craft;?>" <?php if ($check_craft == 1) echo "checked";?>>
  <div id="contentM3" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="mod_craft" value="" id="mod_craft" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 " placeholder="No Oficio">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="mod_datecraft" value="" id="mod_datecraft" class="form-control craftdatetimepicker col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Fecha Oficio">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando operador ternario, si el valor es 1 imprimes `checked`

```
<input type="checkbox" name='mostrar3' id="mostrar3" class='squaredThreex fantasma3 hh' value="<?php echo $check_craft;?>" "<?php  ($check_craft === 1)? 'checked':'' ?>">
```